# Executando método async no Load

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async

Tenho um método `void` que executa um procedimento no banco de dados e não tem retorno, chamo esse método no *load* do formulário, porém quando o procedimento demora o programa trava.

Como que passo esse método para `async` para não travar a aplicação?

```
  private  void AccountsReceivable() 
  {
            using  (SqlConnection con = clsdb.AbreBanco())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("procedimento", con))
                {
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd1.CommandTimeout = 20000;
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
   }


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Task Receivable  = new Task(AccountsReceivable);
  Receivable.Start();
}
```

Comment: se mudar o método para async, o "Form_Load" também deveria ser, senão vais ter de usar um `Wait`, o que vai forçar o outro método a ficar síncrono... pedes iniciar uma nova task e deixar executar sem bloquear o processamento. Pode fazer isso por exemplo usando `Task.Run`

Comment: @RicardoPontual Pode me dar um exemplo usando o código acima, não entendi a parte de criar uma nova `task` e deixar executar sem bloquear.

Comment: @mba esse método que você executa no banco você diz que é demorado e que por isso que "trava" seu programa, será que se você melhorasse a query, como por exemplo  em um Select  com comando WITH (NOLOCK)  que indica que não será necessário bloquear a tabela durante a leitura dos dados, não ajudaria??? ex: "SELECT COUNT(Nome) FROM TabelaPessoas WITH (NOLOCK) "

Answer (score 1):

Antes de tornar assíncrono você deveria consertar um problema grave que é esse `try-catch` sem fazer nada.

Não faço a menor ideia o que está querendo fazer com esse `Task` em `Form1_Load()`, mas retire isso, tudo deve ser resolvido no outro método, isto se realmente a *query* tem demorado muito, caso contrário no compensa.

Seria algo assim (pelo menos uma implementação ingênua, sem saber oque realmente precisa):

```
private async Task AccountsReceivable() {
    using  (SqlConnection con = clsdb.AbreBanco())
    using (var cmd1 = new SqlCommand("procedimento", con)) {
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd1.CommandTimeout = 20000;
        await cmd1.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Async/LoadingDataInForm.cs).

[Pode ler com mais detalhes e adaptar ao que precisa](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1121822/Using-Async-Await-Task-Methods-With-SQL-Queries-NE).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutenonquery?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_BeginExecuteNonQuery_System_AsyncCallback_System_Object_).

Comment: Esta no `load` para ser executado automático sem ação do usuário. Dessa forma esta sendo executado automático? O  `try-catch` no código original tem `log` que informa se houve alguma exceção, achei que não seria relevante na pergunta.

Comment: Se não é relevante tire ele. Não sei o que quer dizer com automático, isto será executado. Nem sei se é o que quer, apenas é oque resolve o problema que você relatou. Código assíncrono precisa ser feito feito certo para o que quer, e requer entendimento de como ele funciona para atender a demanda exata.

Comment: Editei a pergunta sem ele. Automático que eu quero dizer é que assim que abrir o formulário o método sera executado sem precisar um evento clique. Por isso estava chamando no `load`.

Comment: Será se você chamar esse método.

Comment: Mas quando eu chamo dessa forma `Task Receivable  = new Task(AccountsReceivable);
            Receivable.Start();` ele  me diz que tem o tipo de retorno incorreto.

Comment: Mas é pra chamar o método normal, conforme eu escrevi, eu não sei o que você fez aí, jogue fora isso, não invente coisas que não entende.

Comment: Edita sua reposta, para funcionar dessa forma tenho que colocar o `load` como `async`  e chamar  o método usando `await AccountsReceivable();`  OBS: "não invente coisas que não entende" esse tipo de comentário é desnecessário no tópico e fórum.